# Differentiate string search in text on python

Tags: python

on python i'm doing a script on which you do multiple searches of strings in a text and based on the results populate an array. In some cases, however, the searches are very similar, for example
Search 1: "...N: 78"
Search 2: "...N: 7"

Clearly in this case search 2 will also include the results of search 1, which I don't want. Is there a way to refine the search, for example by also searching for a space after 7, so that 78 is not included?
Below the code segment concerned:

```
if 'bandNR: 7' in line:
  a[tr][8] = 'n7 '
 if 'bandNR: 78' in line:
  a[tr][10] = 'n78'
```

Thanks!

Comment: One straightforward way is to first filter out the more specific one, then filter the less specific ones: Which would become `if 'bandNR: 78' in line: .... elif 'bandNR: 7' in line: ...`. But this gets more complicated the more options you have.

Comment: The other approach, which I guess would be more commonly used, but takes some time to learn, is to use regular expressions, where you can indicate that the search pattern you are looking for should end with a single digit (so 78 would be excluded): `pattern = r'bandNR: \d([^\d]|$)'` (which also accounts for the possibility of the search string ending with the search pattern).

Comment: can you update the question providing a sample text and corresponding sample searches in the text? @Tork98